# Remove trailing new line from 'clipboard' to prevent execution on the terminal?

Tags: clipboard, newlines

Is there some way to run whatever you copy to the 'clipboard' through some sort of filter? Ideally to strip out the trailing newline from something you copy, so that it doesn't auto-run in the terminal?

This is what it looks like when I copy the test in question, and I sometimes forget this is a new line.
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good modern terminals support [bracketed paste](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste): when you use the terminal's paste command, it sends special escape sequences around the clipboard content. If your shell supports bracketed paste, it'll paste the clipboard content including any control characters as-is, and in particular a trailing newline will not trigger the execution of the command.

Zsh ≥5.1 supports bracketed paste and has it on by default. Older versions [can be taught](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/pull/1698). Bash ≥4.4 supports bracketed paste if you add [`set enable-bracketed-paste on`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#IDX21) to `~/.inputrc`.

If your terminal or shell doesn't support bracketed paste, you could define a shell function that pastes without the trailing newline.

In zsh, the following command recalls the content of the clipboard, minus trailing newlines, and brings it up for editing (even if there are multiple lines):

```
print -z -- "`xsel -b`"
```

In bash, you can push the content of the clipboard minus trailing newlines to the history stack. After this, press <kbd>Up</kbd> to bring up the command for editing.

```
history -s -- "`xsel -b`"
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use `cat` to paste in a file, do whatever you like and then execute it.

For this case:

```
$ cat > tmp
[paste][Ctrl+D]
$ tr -d '\n' <tmp | xclip # this remove all "new line" characters 
                          #  and copy back to clipboard
```

Comment: And how could I use it on GUI level when I copy some command from browser (like Stack answer) to my shell... In fact I ruined my OS yesterday because of such copy-paste :)

Answer (score 3):

Since version 0.13 (released 2016-09), `xclip` seems to have an undocumented option `-r`, which does exactly what is needed: removes the very last newline character from the text. See https://github.com/astrand/xclip/issues/7. At least it works for me on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

This makes `\ev` insert the clipboard without newlines in bash 4.0 and later:

```
pasteline() {
  local input=$(xsel -b)
  input=${input//$'\n'}
  READLINE_LINE=${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$input${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}
  READLINE_POINT=$((READLINE_POINT+${#input}))
}

bind -x '"\ev": pasteline'
```

Replace `xsel -b` with `pbpaste` and install bash 4 in OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I realized we can do it in one line, inspired from @RSFalcon7 answer

by using `xsel`, to copy to primary selection

```
cat | tr -d '\n' | xsel

[paste], 2 times[Ctrl-D]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [here document](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to queue up your pastes and then process the input to remove the unwanted chars.

So you would do ...

```
args=$(tr '\n' ' ' << EOI
    [PASTE]
    [PASTE]
    [PASTE]
EOI
)
```

Your desired output is saved in `$args`.

An full example:

```
[root@rpm-server feature]# args=$(tr '\n' ' ' << EOI
        ../../root/bin/gitLatestTag.py
        ../../root/bin/sri-build-rpm
        ../../root/bin/sriBuild.py_orig
        ../../root/bin/sriBuild2.py
EOI
)
[root@rpm-server feature]# echo $args
../../root/bin/gitLatestTag.py ../../root/bin/sri-build-rpm ../../root/bin/sriBuild.py_orig ../../root/bin/sriBuild2.py
[root@rpm-server feature]#
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use

```
alias copy='xargs echo -n | xsel -ib'
alias paste='xsel -ob | xargs echo -n'
```

in my bashrc
you can pipe to and from these aliases