# Copy a long single-line text from a terminal with undesired change-line

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, text

`locate ... | less` outputs a long path, which is shown as several lines in the terminal, although it is actually a single line.

I copy the path from the terminal by  selecting the text with mouse and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. 
When I paste it into a text file, I get unwanted change-line in the text, exactly  in the same way that it is shown in the terminal.

But I remember sometimes I can copy a long path output by `locate ... | less`, without introducing  unwanted line-change, and sometimes I can't. I don't realize if I do something differently.

So I wonder how to make sure the problem will not happen? Thanks!

My OS: Ubuntu 12.04.

My terminal: Gnome Terminal 3.4.1.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove trailing new line from 'clipboard' to prevent execution on the terminal?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96357/remove-trailing-new-line-from-clipboard-to-prevent-execution-on-the-terminal)

Comment: But Ctrl+Shift+C can sometime copy a long line without copying  change-line. Still different problems, I think.

Comment: So your Q is more about why or how to control this behavior?

Comment: Yes. I copy text out of the terminal using the shortcut key (which I guess is the quickest way), not by directing the output to a file

Comment: Is there anything more about when the behavior is one way vs. the other?

Comment: That is my question: why I don't get the same behavior always, and how I can  get the desired behavior always. I don't notice any difference that I do, but I might miss something.

Comment: `more` vs `less`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I have always been using `less` after `locate`. it is beyond my understanding that  copied texts of its output sometimes contains the undesired new-line, and sometimes don't.

Comment: It depends how the pager writes the lines. If it lets the terminal emulator wrap the lines or does the wrapping by itself (without using ways to trick the terminal emulator into thinking it's a wrapped line). AFAIK, `less` does use those tricks. Can you reproduce the problem easily? Do you use screen/tmux? Do you pass options to `less` (via aliases, `$LESS` or other)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The command I run is `locate -i blahblah | less`, and then I copy a long line of `less` output  by mouse selecting it and hitting ctrl+shift+C. I sometimes can copy the whole line without undesired new-lines in the middle, but sometimes with them. I don't know when the latter will happen, and it seems unpredictable to me, or I may miss something that I did differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of copying what is displayed on the terminal (only what fits on the screen, with), copy the actual text. Use one of the external utilities [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) or [xclip](http://xclip.sourceforge.net/) (they have mostly the same features, I'll use xsel in this answer) to copy data from or to the X clipboard. To copy to the clipboard, pass the desired content on standard input. When pasting from the clipboard, the content is written to standard output.

In less, use the `|` command to pipe a bunch of lines through a command. Scroll to the first line you want to act on, type `mm` to set a mark, scroll to the last line, and type `|mxsel -b` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Two marks are predefined: `^` for the beginning of the file, `$` for the end of the file. Thus, to copy the whole file, use `<|$xsel -b`. To copy a single line, use `mm|mxsel -b` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Remove the `-b` option to copy to the primary selection instead of the clipboard.

Answer (score 6):

The real behavior of this is the following:

if you are in `less` and you have a file with a very long line, then if you scroll over the long line down and scroll back up, you have multiple lines, when copying the whole text. After that, when you scroll the splitted lines down over the bottom of the terminal and scroll the lines up again, the line breaks will be removed again.

For visualization:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can **copy** the lines of output **without extra newlines** (line breaks) if the text was **output directly** to the terminal.
The terminal can keep track of where the real line ends are.

But if the lines were output by `less` or a similar `pager` program, the terminal does not know where the newlines are. The pager uses the terminal as a full screen of characters, and tells the terminal "put these characters there" and operations like scrolling. But, for the terminal, there's no way to see where newlines are intended.

Comment: I found that sometimes I  copy the line breaks and sometimes I don't. It is inconsistent across time. Today both happened when I Ctrl-shift-c from `locate <something> | less` in two different cases.

Comment: Less draws its screen itself, normally, so that the terminal does not see where lines end. But less can be configured do actually do nothing for short files fitting the screen heigt. So it's possible that the difference between the cases was that less was in a different mode. (take a look at `echo $LESS`, maybe there are interesting options for less.)

Comment: @Tim this has been bugging me for years too. Maybe @niknah's answer suggests the cause? I often switch between `-S` mode so maybe that makes it worse too.

Comment: @Tim: I discovered something that might or might not be true on your OS & less version:  the behavior of copy varies depending on how I've arrived at the target line in less. If I'm searching forwards then the copy doesn't include the wrapping newlines (i.e., it copies the original long line content).  However, if I've searched backwards through the file to get to the target line, then the copy includes the newlines and splits the long line into multiple separate lines.  Seems consistent across Mac and Linux for me.

Answer (score 2):

In `less`, if you select wrapped multiple lines of text and then copy it, it'll come down as one line.

If you press <kbd>PgUp</kbd> then copy the same text, it'll come down as multiple lines.

<kbd>PgDn</kbd> is fine, arrows are fine.  But <kbd>PgUp</kbd> causes the text to be split up.

Comment: That's not exactly the real cause of the behavior. See my answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445590/105308

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to copy & paste, I use `cat` instead of `less` or `more` and then the terminal captures it as it actually is rather than as it is being displayed.